# SQL server, Converting Seconds to Minutes, Hours, Days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database column containing an integer value that represents a systems up time in seconds. I'd really like a query to be able to show me that up time in a easy to read format day(s) hour(s) minute(s) but I'm not quite sure how to do it. A lot of examples I've found appear to use parameters as an example but never much of how to use it in a select function.

I need the time to be the same as what's displayed on a website too. I tried one query earlier and its added days and removed minutes. Can anyone help me out?

Source data:

```
PDT0014 6141
PDT0008 4990
PDT0024 840227
PDT0033 2301
PDT0035 5439
PDT0005 3434
PDT0019 5482
```

Sample code:

```
SELECT tblAssets.AssetName, 
(case when tblAssets.Uptime> (24*60*60) 
        then 
            cast(datepart(day,datediff(dd, 0, dateadd(second, tblAssets.Uptime, 0))) as varchar(4))
        +   ' Day(s) ' + convert(varchar(2), dateadd(second, tblAssets.Uptime, 0), 108) +' Hour(s)' 
    else
            convert(varchar(5), dateadd(second, tblAssets.Uptime, 0), 108) + ' Hour(s) Minute(s) ' 
    end) AS Uptime
FROM tblAssets
```

Desired Query Output:

```
PDT0014 01:42 Hour(s) Minute(s) 
PDT0008 01:23 Hour(s) Minute(s) 
PDT0024 10 Day(s) 17 Hour(s)
PDT0033 00:38 Hour(s) Minute(s) 
PDT0035 01:30 Hour(s) Minute(s) 
PDT0005 00:57 Hour(s) Minute(s) 
PDT0019 01:31 Hour(s) Minute(s)
```

Comment: show us what you have tried and the current output along with what you would like the output to be. Sample code and output will help you get better answers.

Comment: CONVERT(varchar, uptime / 86400) + " days " + CONVERT(varchar, (uptime % 86400) / 3600) + " hours " + ...

Comment: I've edited it. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: Wait, is `Output:` your *desired* output, or the output you're getting now (that isn't good enough)?

Comment: Nah that's the output my query was giving, not the desired one!

Comment: To be ultra clear (and since folks often ignore comments), you should add a code block that shows the actual output you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tend to use:

```
CAST(FLOOR(seconds / 86400) AS VARCHAR(10))+'d ' +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(SECOND, Seconds, '19000101'), 8)
```

The top part just gets your days as an integer, the bottom uses SQL-Server's convert to convert a date into a varchar in the format HH:mm:ss after converting seconds into a date.

e.g.

```
SELECT  Formatted = CAST(FLOOR(seconds / 86400) AS VARCHAR(10))+'d ' +
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(SECOND, Seconds, '19000101'), 8),
        Seconds
FROM    (   SELECT  TOP 10 
                    Seconds = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Object_ID) * 40000)
            FROM    sys.all_Objects
            ORDER BY Object_ID
        ) S
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dbc1/2)**

*N.B. Change* `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(..` *to* `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(..` *to keep the seconds in the result*

**EDIT**

If you don't want seconds and need to round to the nearest minute rather than truncate you can use:

```
SELECT  Formatted = CAST(FLOOR(ROUND(Seconds / 60.0, 0) * 60 / 86400) AS VARCHAR(10))+'d ' +
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(SECOND, ROUND(Seconds / 60.0, 0) * 60, '19000101'), 8),
        Seconds
FROM    (   SELECT  Seconds = 3899
        ) S
```

I have just replaced each reference to the column `seconds` with:

```
ROUND(Seconds / 60.0, 0) * 60
```

So before doing the conversion rounding your seconds value to the nearest minute

Comment: great query, does the fact it drops seconds affect rounding at all?

Comment: Yes. It will truncate the duration, so 1 hour, 4 minutes and 59 seconds will show as `0d 01:04`, and won't round up (as it probably should to `0d 01:05`.

Answer (score 15):

Depending on the output you want:

```
DECLARE @s INT = 139905;

SELECT                CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @s /60/60/24) + ' Day(s), ' 
  +                   CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @s /60/60 % 24) 
  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),  @s /60 % 60), 2) 
  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),  @s % 60), 2);
```

Result:

```
1 Day(s), 14:51:45
```

Or:

```
DECLARE @s INT = 139905;

SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @s /60/60/24)   + ' Day(s), ' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @s /60/60 % 24) + ' Hour(s), '
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),  @s /60 % 60)    + ' Minute(s), ' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),  @s % 60)        + ' Second(s).';
```

Result:

```
1 Day(s), 14 Hour(s), 51 Minute(s), 45 Second(s).
```

You can replace `60/60/24` with `86400` etc. but I find it better self-documenting if you leave in the /seconds/minutes/hours calculations. And if you are going against a table, just use `column_name` in place of `@s`.

Comment: Alright I'm liking the look of the second query, where would I read the column name into it though?

Comment: You would replace `@s` with the column name.

Comment: Well I'm a fool aren't I. I've been scratching my head at these parameters wondering how i could apply it to my situation!

Answer (score 5):

You can convert seconds to days by dividing by 86400

You can convert seconds to hours by dividing by 3600, but you need to get the remainder
(by subtracting off the total days converted to hours)

You can convert seconds to minutes by dividing by 60, but you need to get the remainder (by subtracting off the total hours converted to minutes)

Seconds you can just report, but like minutes you want to only report the remainder of seconds (by sutracting off the total minutes converted to seconds)

```
SELECT      FLOOR( UpTime / 86400 ) AS DAYS
        ,   FLOOR( ( UpTime / 3600 ) - FLOOR( UpTime / 86400 ) * 24 ) AS HOURS
        ,   FLOOR( ( UpTime / 60 ) - FLOOR( UpTime / 3600 ) * 60 ) AS MINUTES
        ,   UpTime - FLOOR( UpTime / 60 ) * 60 AS SECONDS
FROM        ( SELECT 269272 AS UpTime ) AS X
```

`269272` represents 3 days (259200 seconds), 2 hours (7200 seconds), 47 minutes (2820 seconds) and 52 seconds.

This query produces:

```
| DAYS | HOURS | MINUTES | SECONDS |
------------------------------------
|    3 |     2 |      47 |      52 |
```

Substituting 125 (2 minutes, 5 seconds) for 259200 will produce:

```
| DAYS | HOURS | MINUTES | SECONDS |
------------------------------------
|    0 |     0 |       2 |       5 |
```

To convert this to a string representation, you can use SQL Server 2012's FORMAT function:

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN DAYS > 0 THEN
                FORMAT( DAYS, '##' ) + ' Day(s) ' + FORMAT( HOURS, '##' ) + ' Hour(s)'
            ELSE
                FORMAT( HOURS, '##' ) + ':' + FORMAT( MINUTES, '##' ) + ' Hour(s) Minute(s)'
        END AS UpTimeString
FROM (
    SELECT      FLOOR( UpTime / 86400 ) AS DAYS
            ,   FLOOR( ( UpTime / 3600 ) - FLOOR( UpTime / 86400 ) * 24 ) AS HOURS
            ,   FLOOR( ( UpTime / 60 ) - FLOOR( UpTime / 3600 ) * 60 ) AS MINUTES
            ,   UpTime - FLOOR( UpTime / 60 ) * 60 AS SECONDS
    FROM        ( SELECT 125 AS UpTime ) AS X
) AS UptimeSubselect
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Looks like a great bit of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach using `DATEPART()`:

```
DECLARE @S INT = 86472,
        @START DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME,0)
DECLARE @END DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND,@S, @START)

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(DAY,@END)-1) + ' Day(s) ' +
       RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),100+DATEPART(HOUR, @END)),2) + ':' +
       RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),100+DATEPART(MINUTE, @END)),2) + ':' +
       RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),100+DATEPART(SECOND, @END)),2)
```

If you don't need to format time part:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(DAY,@END)-1) + ' Day(s) ' +
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(HOUR, @END)) + '  Hour(s)' +
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(MINUTE, @END)) + ' Minute(s)' +
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(SECOND, @END)) + ' Second(s)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Seconds INT = 86200;
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), 
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Seconds / 60 / 60 % 24)
+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Seconds / 60 % 60)
+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Seconds % 60) AS TIME), 100) AS [HH:MM:SS (AM/PM)]
```

[image]