# if time is more than 60 minutes then show in hours in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[IBS_Podiumsummryaveragetime]
@locid integer=null
as 
begin
set nocount on;
select  avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate )) as Avgstaytime,
 avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.PAICdate )) as  Avgparkingtime, 
 avg( datediff(mi,t.Paydate, t.DelDate )) as AvgDelivarytime 
 from (select top 10 * from transaction_tbl where locid=@locid and dtime >= getdate()-7 order by transactID desc ) t  
 end
```

if average time i am getting more than 60 minutes then i want to show in hours..how i can do this?
any help is appreciable??

Comment: answered before here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19298717/3248346

Comment: Can you show sample output for what you want?  I mean, do you want some in hours and some in minutes?  That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: now result is getting in minutes..if the result is more than 60 minutes,,then i want show that result in hours,,that s all

Comment: why don't you use a case statement, if mins is greater than 60 does query X if less than 60 do Y.

Comment: can you show once please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't type this in the comments so I've added it as an answer:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate )) <= 60 
          THEN CAST(avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate )), varchar)
      ELSE 
          CAST(avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate )) / 60, varchar) + ":" + CAST(avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate )) % 60, varchar)
   END
```

Comment: I'd prefer an ELSE to the 2nd WHEN condition.

Comment: @KarlKieninger, I agree. Code modified.

Comment: sir i am searching for conversion code..then i will let u know wethar this is working fine or not

Comment: Your answer to @GordonLinoff in the question comments wasn't clear. How do you want to display hours? i.e. is 61 minutes 1, 1:1, 1.017? is 90 minutes 1, 1.5, 1:30, 2?

Comment: if 61 minutes then i want to show 1:1 Min,,if 90 minute then i want to show 1:30 ,,if 130 minute then i want to show 2:10 like that

Comment: I've modified the query above. Please check the syntax, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Variations on @I.K.'s theme's (which I up voted)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN avg(datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate)) > 60 
            THEN CAST(avg(datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate))/60 AS VARCHAR(3)) + ':' 
            ELSE ''
       END
       + CAST(avg(datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate)) % 60  AS VARCHAR(2)) 

--OR

SELECT CASE WHEN avg(datediff(hour,t.dtime, t.DelDate)) > 0 
            THEN CAST(avg(datediff(hour,t.dtime, t.DelDate)) AS VARCHAR(3)) + ':' 
            ELSE ''
       END
       + CAST(avg(datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate)) % 60  AS VARCHAR(2))
```

Comment: I'm upvoting, because you put lengths in for `varchar()`.

Comment: but one problem,,in the case of minutes,,if example if the average time is only 5 minutes,,then it s showing null.