# How to format a big sum of seconds as hrs and mins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-superset

I have a string column `durationinseconds`. I want to take `sum(durationinseconds)` and make it human-readable as hrs and mins.

Example:
Total sum of durationinseconds is 54000000300 seconds.
Now I want to convert and get it as:

```
15000000 hrs 5 min
```

Want to query this into Apache superset.

I tried to use query below but not getting correct value:

```
SELECT 
    sum(durationInSeconds)
    , FLOOR( ( sum(durationInSeconds) / 3600 ) - FLOOR( sum(durationInSeconds )/ 86400 ) * 24 ) AS HOURS 
    , FLOOR( ( sum(durationInSeconds )/ 60 ) - FLOOR( sum(durationInSeconds) / 3600 ) * 60 ) AS MINUTES 
 FROM tickets
```

Below is the output I am getting which is not correct:

```
duration in seconds=395069295299 hr=6 min =54
```

Comment: This page seems to solve your request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298405/sql-server-converting-seconds-to-minutes-hours-days

Comment: @Cyrus, the linked question is about SQL Server and barely applicable.

Comment: If you don't want to report days separately from days then why are you subtracting that portion out?

Answer (score 2):

Cast to integer (`bigint` to hold the big value) and multiply with `interval '1 sec'`:

```
SELECT '54000000300'::bigint * interval '1 sec';
```

Use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to format  exactly as requested:

```
SELECT to_char('54000000300'::bigint * interval '1 sec', 'FMHH24" hrs "FMMI" min"');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=7cb8267ffac1597198e22099f19b0872)*

Applied to your query:

```sql
SELECT to_char(sum("durationInSeconds"::bigint) * interval '1 sec', 'FMHH24" hrs "FMMI" min"')
FROM   tickets
```

Assuming you actually double-quoted the unfortunate CaMeL-case name "durationInSeconds". Else drop the double-quotes. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

And the cast to `bigint` is only needed if it's really a "string column" - also an unfortunate design for a numeric or interval quantity.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

> `to_char(interval)` formats `HH` and `HH12` as shown on a 12-hour clock, for example zero hours and 36 hours both output as 12, while `HH24` outputs the full hour value, which can exceed 23 in an `interval` value.

`FM` in the template pattern stands for:

> fill mode (suppress leading zeroes and padding blanks)

The multiplication is typically faster than string concatenation.
`to_char()` is also fast and deals with corner cases nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  ((54000000300/3600.0)::text || 'hrs')::interval;
    interval    
----------------
 15000000:05:00
```

Comment: tried using the below query but it is throwing error as SQL paraphase failed         SELECT durationInSeconds,
((durationInSeconds/3600.0)::text || 'hrs')::interval;
FROM tickets

Comment: In what client are you running this? There should be more to the error message an `ERROR` and possibly  `CONTEXT` and `HINT` section also.

Comment: this is the error:Error: SQL parse failed

Encountered ":" at line 1, column 54.

Was expecting one of: ")" ... "ORDER" ... "LIMIT" ... "OFFSET" ... "FETCH" ... "," ... "UNION" ... "INTERSECT" ... "EXCEPT" ... "MINUS" ... "." ... "NOT" ... "IN" ... "<" ... "<=" ... ">" ... ">=" ... "=" ... "<>" ... "!=" ... "BETWEEN" ... "LIKE" ... "SIMILAR" ... "+" ... "-" ... "*" ... "/" ... "%" ... "||" ... "AND" ... "OR" ... "IS" ... "MEMBER" ... "SUBMULTISET" ... "CONTAINS" ... "OVERLAPS" ... "EQUALS" ... "PRECEDES" ... "SUCCEEDS" ... "IMMEDIATELY" ... "MULTISET"  Runing this query in apache druid

Comment: You need to show the actual query properly formatted and the error message properly formatted as an update to your question. Also try the query using `psql`, that will eliminate layers of potential errors.